# Chrome: weird image at the bottom of my Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, user-agent

I am working on a website (using Wordpress, version 3.6.1, Twenty Thirteen theme).
When I open the website on Chrome there is this image at the bottom of the page.

[image]

I googled and found that it could be because of this HP Website Logon plugin installed in my Chrome.
But it only happens with the website I am currently working on. The plugin has been installed ever since I bought my laptop 2 year ago and this is the first that it happens.

Can someone please tell me how to fix it? Is it my Wordpress installation?

Regards.

Comment: Whats the URL of the website?

Comment: @Anagio Sorry for the late reply. It's on my local machine. I am using Wamp. I thought it was because of Wordpress so I decided to create a simple html page. Still having the same issue :-(

Comment: Try viewing in another browser

Comment: @Anagio Yes, it was fine if viewed in other browsers. I have given up, I have disabled the HP Website Logon plugin in Chrome. Thanks anyway.